# Sinch IOS SDK + App crash when hangup Video call

Tags: video, sinch

I am integrating Sinch in my IOS Application for video calling, I am able to add it successfully and video call is coming and showing video too. But my issue is when I hang up the video call, My app is a crash which shows below messages:

Error 1:

> Fatal error in ../../../webrtc/modules/video_coding/utility/h264_bitstream_parser.cc, line 271
>   last system error: 316
>   Check failed: ParseNonParameterSetNalu(slice, length, nalu_type)
>   Failed to parse picture slice.
>   Message : (h264_bitstream_parser.cc:90): ParseNonParameterSetNalu: FAILED: slice_reader.ReadExponentialGolomb(&golomb_tmp)

Error 2:

> Fatal error in ../../../webrtc/modules/video_coding/utility/h264_bitstream_parser.cc, line 271
>   last system error: 316
>   Check failed: ParseNonParameterSetNalu(slice, length, nalu_type)
>   Failed to parse picture slice.

Please suggest me, how to solve that issue.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Ever find a solution?

Comment: it was due to simulator while when i was tested in the device, it was working fine.